# 3 column responsive layout with fixed sidebar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi I'm looking to create a 3 column responsive layout where one of the column (sidebar) is in fixed position.

Both sidebars have a width set in percents and also min & max-width properties in pixels.
And I want that the content in the middle to fill all the space between the two sidebars please.

I beleive I can calculate the width of the sidebars using JS but I'm looking for the best approach hopefully using only CSS please.

It needs to support only IE9 not below.

I'm attaching a drawing for better understanding and will appreciate your help.

[image: a drawing for better understanding]

Comment: Thank you for reply Ankur, I have tried several ways playing with the layout but I don't know how to make the content in the middle to fill the whole space when the sidebars are getting to they min/max-width.
I tried also setting the display property to "table" but unfortunately no luck.
or I'm missing something small or my whole approach is wrong.
So I came here hope to find a direction using your help please.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fV9k/). Please see if it's what are you looking for.

Here the html code:

```
<header>Fixed Header</header>
<div id='container'>
    <nav>Navigation</nav>
    <article>Article</article>
    <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
<aside>Fixed Aside</aside>
```

and here the css:

```
body
{
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

header
{
    height:50px;
    background:rgb(200,200,0);
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
}

aside
{
    height:50px;
    background:rgb(200,0,0);
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    right:0;
    width:20%;
    height:700px;
}

#container
{
    margin-top:50px;
}

nav
{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    height:700px;
    background:rgb(200,100,100);
}

article
{
    padding-right:20%;
}

footer
{
    clear:both;
    padding-right:20%;
    width:80%;
    background:gray;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Luca, but this is not exactly what I need, I need the sidebars to have min&max-width set in pixels please.
and I also need the sidebars to be 100% height and not a fixed height.
and as you can see in my drawing the fixed sidebar is above the footer as it's height is 100%.

Comment: I edit my [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6fV9k/1/). What do you mean with min and max width? it must depend by media queries?

Comment: @GilGoldshlager: Now that Luca's done the lion's share for you, let's see your attempts and then perhaps we can provide additional direction.

Comment: @LucaDetomi the min&max-width to the sidebars are always being set, not using media queries.
for example:
`width: 20%; min-width: 200px; max-width: 300px;`------------------@Frankenscarf I see what you mean but my code will not contribute any help in this case.
I'm not necessary asking for the result code from you guys, even that it will be great and of course much appreciated, I do know how to code and looking for the right approach/direction that will lead me to the right result please as I never faced with a layout such like this in the past.

Comment: Ok Gil, please let me know what are defects my last update still have ;-)

Comment: @LucaDetomi if I'm adding min&max-width to the sidebars the calculation of the padding of the content is getting wrong as you set it in your code to 20% but it's not always 20% because of the min&max-width of the sidebars.
I updated your code so you will can see what I'm talking about please: http://jsfiddle.net/6fV9k/2/

Answer (score 0):

You should try Bootstrap classes, they work perfectly